# How to get Chatter photo fileId?

Tags: chatter, connect-api

I'm trying to use [`ConnectApi.ChatterUsers.getUserBatch()`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterUsers_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterUsers_getUserBatch) to migrate users' photos. However, the `ConnectApi.User` object that I get only seems to have access, through its [`photo`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_connectapi_output_User.htm) property, to the [`ConnectApi.Photo.photoVersionId`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_connectapi_output_photo.htm) value. However, when using [`ConnectApi.ChatterUsers.setPhoto()`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterUsers_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterUsers_setPhoto) I need to actually provide a *`fileId`*, not a `photoVersionId`.

My question is: Knowing the `photoVersionId`, how do I get the *`fileId`*?

Below is a sample anonymous Apex code block that illustrates what I'm trying to do. It will reproduce the same error I've described above.

```
Id fromUserId = '005j0000000Z1Lx';
Id toUserId = '005j0000000Zqt3';

for (ConnectApi.BatchResult eachResult :
    ConnectApi.ChatterUsers.getUserBatch(
        null, new List<Id> { fromUserId })) {
    ConnectApi.User eachUser = (ConnectApi.User)eachResult.getResult();
    ConnectApi.ChatterUsers.setPhoto(null, toUserId, eachUser.photo.photoVersionId, null);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BritishBoy above is correct -- so the only way I could find to access the User Photos is through the URL:

```
Id fromUserId = '005o0000001drai';
Id toUserId = '005o0000000ygsZ';

for (ConnectApi.BatchResult eachResult :
     ConnectApi.ChatterUsers.getUserBatch(
         null, new List<Id> { fromUserId })) {
             ConnectApi.User eachUser = (ConnectApi.User)eachResult.getResult();
             ConnectApi.Photo p = ConnectApi.ChatterUsers.getPhoto(null, fromUserId);
             Http h = new Http();
             HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
             req.setEndPoint(p.fullEmailPhotoUrl);
             req.setMethod('GET');
             HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);
             Blob b = res.getBodyAsBlob();
             ConnectApi.ChatterUsers.setPhoto(null, toUserId, 
                 new ConnectApi.BinaryInput(b, res.getHeader('Content-Type'),'user3.jpg'));
         }
```

Note that there's a couple caveats with the method above:

1. You need to authorize your Salesforce instance as a "[Remote Site](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_remote_site_settings.htm)"
2. I was only able to get this to work with the [fullEmailPhotoUrl](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_connectapi_output_photo.htm?CSHID) property, as it doesn't need authentication

Comment: For Group Photos, all you would need to do is replace "ChatterUsers" with "ChatterGroups"!

Answer (score 4):

I saw [this](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcodepre/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_connectapi_input_PhotoInput.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fapex_connectapi_input_PhotoInput.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp) in the docs re PhotoInput, so I am thinking it can't be done?

> Images uploaded on the Group page and on the User page don’t have file
>   IDs and therefore can’t be used.